# Android Option Menu showing as list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I have created a menu which is activated on clicking the menu button on the device however it is showing as a list

[image: Menu]

My  in res/menu/menu.xml code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menuRefresh"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
     android:title="Refresh"/>
<item android:id="@+id/menuAbout"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
     android:title="About"/>
</menu>
```

and in my main activity i have:

```
//Initiate Menu XMl file
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Even handling for individual menu items selected
     * Identity single menu item by its id
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuRefresh:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Refresh Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menuAbout:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "About Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

If i select an item from the list, i get the notification as expected.

How do i make the menu look like the Options menu on the [android dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)?

Answer (score 2):

That is what the options menu looks like on new devices, a list. If you want your options to be part of the top bar (called the Action Bar), add `android:showAsAction` to your xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menuRefresh"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
     android:title="Refresh"
      android:showAsAction = "always"/>
<item android:id="@+id/menuAbout"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
     android:title="About"
     android:showAsAction = "always"/>
</menu>
```

For demo purposes, I chose the attribute to be `"always"`, but you have [more options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html):

- `"ifRoom"`
- `"never"`
- `"withText"`
- `"always"`
- `"collapseActionView"`

Comment: Not in "new devices", just in "new themes".

Comment: @cprcrack Then attach a screenshot showing the old menu on a new Android version and I'll delete this answer and upvote yours.

Answer (score 1):

Even in new devices, you can set the theme to an old one and the menu will display in the old 6-item table layout:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme">
```